# Library/content document subscription

Tags: trigger, standard-objects, content

I have a question related to libraries/document content subscriptions.

Someone knows in what object they are stored after a user click on subscribe button?
I have checked here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_content.htm#sforce_api_erd_content
But I cannot find anything relevant to subscriptions. I would like to know the object in order to create a trigger that it is subscribing users to libraries in order to receive an email every time that a document has been updated/uploaded in the library.

Please help me to find the object storing library subscriptions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. This table is not exposed in the API, so you wouldn't be able to subscribe users from the API. There a few old related ideas if you believe in democracy.

I think using Files would give you more flexibility from an API point of view.